# Can't open a ttyUSB port in a daemon

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, daemon

I have a problem with using a port within a daemon in linux.
I use `open` from `fcntl.h` like `serHandle_ = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);` and I get `0` as result when I use it within a daemon. When I use it outside a daemon everything works fine. I've set `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Do you have some idea what the problem may be? Maybe permissions? Even if I start the daemon as superuser I still get `0` as a result from `open`.

Below you can see a code snippet of my class method that should initialize the daemon:

```
Bool DaemonStarter::initialize()
{
  isInitialized_ = false;
  if (workingDirectory_ == "" ||
      !boost::filesystem3::exists(workingDirectory_))
    return false;

  Bool res = true;
  ::setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
  ::openlog(name_.c_str(), LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

  pid_t pid, sid;
  pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0)
  {
    res = res && false;
    ::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pid > 0)
  {
    res = res && true;
    ::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  ::umask(0);

  sid = ::setsid();
  if (sid < 0)
  {
    res = res && false;
    ::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if ((chdir(workingDirectory_.c_str())) < 0)
  {
    res = res && false;
    ::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for (UInt i = ::sysconf (_SC_OPEN_MAX); i > 0; i--)
        ::close (i);

  ::umask(0);

  ::close(STDIN_FILENO);
  ::close(STDOUT_FILENO);
  ::close(STDERR_FILENO);
  isInitialized_ = res;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: A minimal example of your code that demonstrates the issue might be usefull.

Comment: In the daemon, are the standard input and output descriptors (stdin/stdout) closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the standard file descriptors (stdin/stdout/stderr) those file descriptors may then be reused by the next call to `open`. So when `open` returns `0` it's quite normal.

If `open` would have failed, it would have returned `-1`.

I recommend you read the  [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) manual page more closely.

Answer (score 2):

From the `man` pages of `open`: "open()  and  creat()  return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred"

`0` is a perfectly valid file descriptor (and for non-daemon applications, is your `stdin` file descriptor). If `open` were to fail, it would return `-1`, so your code is working fine.